# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add' почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При добавление тегов через консоль выдаёт эту ошибку (она в заголовке)
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True,  related_name='posts')
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)
# Create your models here
```

.
Это я ввожу в консоль

```
from blog.models import *
django_t = (title='django', slug='django')
Post.tags
Post.tags.add(django_t)
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: Вы вводите в консоль абсолютно бессмысленные последовательности символов. Чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: Мне нужно добавить теги к статьям,что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаём новую статью

```
post = Post.objects.create(title='Test', slug='test', body='Lorem ipsum...')
```

или получаем из базы какую-нибудь

```
post = Post.objects.first()
```

Создаём тег

```
tag = Tag.objects.create(title='django', slug='django')
```

И только потом добавляем тег в статью

```
post.tags.add(tag)
```

Соответствующий [раздел документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Впрочем, подозреваю, что вам стоит прочитать всё руководство полностью